# Dump z3's configuration?

Tags: z3, z3py

Is there a way to have Z3 dump all its settings when run from the CLI and from Python?

I have a large optimizer (maxsat) program that runs in 2m from the CLI but never finishes when run in Python and I want to understand what the differences are.  For this test, I create the program in Python, then use "opt.sexpr()" to dump smt to a file that I then tested in the CLI.

It looks like "z3 -p" shows the default CLI settings.  Are those going to be the same as the settings when loading a script, beyond the obvious differences of the (set-option) lines?

And how would one get the same thing from inside Python?

Comment: This is really odd; is there some code you can share that exhibits this behavior so we can experiment ourselves? So far as I know, as long as you don't pass any custom arguments on the CLI, running inside Python or saving to file via `opt.sexpr()` and running that from the CLI shouldn't make a difference. If you're sure this is the case, please report it at z3 issue tracker: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues

Comment: There could also be a difference due to the random seed used, if your problem is sensitive to this value. I’d get the seed from a fast run and use it consistently to see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can set or retrieve global parameters as shown below:

```
#  Demo how to set global parameters
#  Run with a non-existent parameter to get a list of legal parameters
set_param("timeout", 60000 * 1000)  # milliseconds
v = z3.get_param('timeout')
print(f"timeout = {v}")

set_param("verbose", 0)
v = z3.get_param('verbose')
print(f"verbose = {v}")

set_param("sat.phase", "always_false")
v = z3.get_param('sat.phase')
print(f"sat.phase = {v}")
```

I haven't found a way to retrieve `Solver` parameters:

```
#  Demo how to set Solver parameters
s = Solver()
#  Display supported solver parameters
#  s.help()
s.set('shuffle_vars', True)
s.set('threads', 4)

v = s.sexpr()  # does not show any options
print(f"sexpr: {v}")

#  Display parameter reference descriptions
pr = s.param_descrs()
prLen = len(pr)
print(f"prLen = {prLen}")
prSize = pr.size()   #  alias for len(pr)
print(f"prSize = {prSize}")

for i in range(10):   #  not all 413 but only 10 ...
    v = pr.get_name(i)
    print(f"name {i}: {v}")
    v = pr.get_kind(i)
    print(f"kind {i}: {v}")
    v = pr[i]   #  returns the parameter name like get_name(i)
    print(f"{i}: {v}")
```

Unlike `Solver`, `Optimize` does show parameters in `sexpr()`.

```
#  Parameter handling of Optimize()
o = Optimize()
# o.help()
o.set("timeout", 123456)

v = o.sexpr()  # shows all options like (set-option :opt.timeout 123456)
print(f"sexpr: {v}")
```

Using a `Python` checker, I compared the default `Z3` parameters against the actual `z3py` parameter values:

```
import subprocess

def show_non_default_parameters():
    result = subprocess.run('z3 -p', capture_output=True, text=True)
    lines = result.stdout.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('Global'):
            prefix = ""
        elif line.startswith('[module]'):
            prefix = line.split(', ')[0][9:] + '.'
        elif "(default: " in line:
            name = prefix + line[:line.find(' (')].strip()
            dflt = line[line.find('(default: '):][9:-1].strip()
            if dflt != "":
                val = get_param(name)
                if val != dflt:
                    print(f"{name} = {val} (default: {dflt})")
```

The following default deviations are found:
(Z3Py version 4.12.1 - 64 bit Windows checked against Z3 4.11.2 binary)

```
rewriter.ite_extra_rules = true (default: false)
smt.bv.delay = false (default: true)
```

Comparison against Z3 4.12.1 binary yielded no difference.